# How to set Google Map's feature ID from geojson?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

How to set [Google Map's feature's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.Feature) `id` from geojson?

`id` is what returned by `getId()` function.

The following code does not work (prints `undefined`) although `id` property exists in properties:

```
var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  var data = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [131.044, -25.363]
    },
    "properties": {
      "Id": 12
    }
  };
  map.data.addGeoJson(data);
  map.data.forEach(function(feature){
    console.log("Id from Google's feature: " + feature.getId());
  });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dimskraft/hj2t5je3/5/

**UDPATE**

I can write

```
var data = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 13,
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [131.044, -25.363]
    },
```

but won't this be incorrect Geojson?

Comment: indeed it would be incorrect, it should be in the properties object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should pass a second parameter to addGeoJson() method that defines what propery in your GeoJSON will be used as id.

The second parameter is Data.GeoJsonOptions object

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.GeoJsonOptions

So the change will be:

```
map.data.addGeoJson(data, {
    idPropertyName: "Id"
});
```

**Code snippet**

```js
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  var data = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [131.044, -25.363]
    },
    "properties": {
      "Id": 12
    }
  };
  map.data.addGeoJson(data, {
    idPropertyName: "Id"
  });
  
  map.data.forEach(function(feature){
   console.log("Id from Google's feature: " + feature.getId());
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
 <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Google's docs on this isn't super clear but you can also add the options when using the .loadGeoJson method